# Conditional LabelsFormat on Report Builder Chart

Tags: reportbuilder

I am trying to design a SSRS report where the end user can choose whether they want to view certain charts grouped by year or by month. The user chooses a value for the parameter @dategroup to determine this.

If @dategroup is "YEAR" the SQL groups and pulls row counts for the last 6 years. If @dategroup is "MONTH" it groups and pulls the last 6 months. The SQL is working fine, but I am struggling with getting the horizontal axis labels to format correctly on my report builder charts.

My query passes a "cte_date" column to the horizontal axis which is a date field. When the report is grouping by month I use the LabelsFormat properties grab the month part of the date. For example, if the query passes the value 2019-01-01 to the chart the LabelsFormat will convert that to "Jan". In this case the property LabelsFormat value is "MMM". When @dateformat is "YEAR", the horizontal axis in this case would be "2019", LabelsFormat "yyyy".

I have tried customizing the LabelsFormat property to

```
Iif(Parameters!dategroup.Value=YEAR,yyyy,MMM)
```

But this is not returning the desired results (month part if grouped by month, year part if grouped by year). Is there a way to format axis labels (which are dates) based on a parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question was close, it just needed some formatting changes. Add double quotes to the parameter value and formats. Enter the below code into the LabelsFormat property of the axis you want changed.

```
=IIf(Parameters!dategroup.Value="YEAR","yyyy","MMM")
```

If the @dategroup parameter is set to "YEAR", it will format the date to show just year. Otherwise, it will format date to the three letter month code.